# Tensorflow SEQ2SEQ training suddenly super slow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I was training seq2seq NMT (neural machine translation) using the code from https://google.github.io/seq2seq/. After I interrupted the training process, restarted process becomes super slow (from 1.2 step/second to 0.07 step/second). Does anyone else have this experience? How do I debug? I have running this for weeks, really do not want to give up... Thanks!~

The last line of normal training,

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.585205, step = 830853 (79.477 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.24179
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.267574, step = 830953 (80.529 sec)
```

The first few line of super slow training ...

```
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.0746058
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.554718, step = 830854 (1340.379 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, after carefully going through log, it appears that one latest update on Cuda created the problem.AND automated updates removed the problem later on now. Here is the log ..

```
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684229: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:405] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684260: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: POSingularity
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684276: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: POSingularity
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684305: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 375.66.0
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.51  Wed Mar 22 10:26:12 PDT 
2017
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
"""
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684352: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 375.51.0
2017-06-02 22:47:22.684368: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:303] kernel version 375.51.0 does not match DSO version 375.66.0 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
```